# pandas: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'transform'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm quite new with python and pandas, and I'm stuck with an error. I'm working with audiofiles, and I need to extract some features from audiostreams.

```
def load_features(self, audio_file):
    def stereo_to_mono(x):
        # stereo to mono
        if len(x.shape) > 1 and x.shape[1] > 1:
            print('Converting stereo to mono')
            x = x.mean(axis=1)
        return x

    def cut_or_pad_to_length(x, duration, fs):
        desired_length = int(round(duration * fs))
        length = len(x)
        diff = length - desired_length
        abs_diff = abs(diff)
        if diff < 0:
            print('Padding')
            # put the short signal in the middle
            pad_before = abs_diff // 2
            pad_after = abs_diff - pad_before
            x = np.lib.pad(x, (pad_before, pad_after), 'constant')
        elif diff > 1:
            print('Cutting')
            # cut the beginning
            x = x[0:desired_length]
        return x

    def adjust_input(x, fs):
        x = stereo_to_mono(x)
        x = cut_or_pad_to_length(x, 2.0, fs)
        return x

    #x is data, fs is samplerate
    x, fs = sf.read(audio_file)
    x0 = adjust_input(x, fs)

    # pitchgram
    x_features = self.ch.transform(x0)

    if self.scaler is not None:
        x_features = self.scaler.transform(x_features.reshape(1, -1)) \

    # 1 data point with 2D features
    x_features = x_features.reshape(1, *x_features.shape)

    return x_features

    def predict_class_label(self, audio_file):
    x_features = self.load_features(audio_file)
    instrument_class = np_utils.probas_to_classes(self.model.predict(x_features, verbose=0))[0]
    label = self.instr_family_le.inverse_transform(instrument_class)
    return label
```

This gives me following error:

```
     File "C:/dipl0m/ml-master/instrument-classification/predict.py", line 104, in predict_probabilities
x_features = self.load_features(audio_file)
     File "C:/dipl0m/ml-master/instrument-classification/predict.py", line 87, in load_features
x_features = self.ch.transform(x0)
     AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'transform'
```

But `x` and `x0` don't seems like dictionary, because I operate with them like lists, but transform gives me that error ... Or am I wrong somewhere? Can't figure it out for a long time.

Comment: Presumably `self.ch` is a `dict`.

Comment: `self.ch` is a `dict` but apparently should be a `pd.DataFrame`

Comment: Doesn't quite look like a minimal example to me. I think you could try to reduce it.

Comment: Trace it with debug or add `print(type(___)) `you will find the solution